# Protobuf C# can't deserialize message from protobufjs

Tags: c#, serialization, protocol-buffers, protobuf.js, protobufjs

Im trying to deserialize a message which is getting posted by a script on a specific website. I have looked through the script and noticed that it uses protobufjs. The message structure is loaded from a JSON file from the server which looks like this stringified:

```
{
"nested":{
    "InteractionCollection":{
        "fields":{
            "interactions":{
                "rule":"repeated",
                "type":"Interaction",
                "id":1
            },
            "mouseMovements":{
            "rule":"repeated",
                "type":"MouseMovement",
                "id":2
            },
            "url":{
                "type":"string",
                "id":3
            },
            "flags":{
                "rule":"repeated",
                "type":"Flag",
                "id":4
            }
        },
        "nested":{
            "Interaction":{
                "fields":{
                    "type":{
                        "type":"string",
                        "id":1
                    },
                    "time":{
                        "type":"int64",
                        "id":2
                    },
                    "elementId":{
                        "type":"string",
                        "id":3
                    },
                    "elementType":{
                        "type":"string",
                        "id":4
                    },
                    "additionalInfo":{
                        "type":"string",
                        "id":5
                    }
                }
            },
            "MouseMovement":{
                "fields":{
                    "time":{
                        "type":"int64",
                        "id":1
                    },
                    "x":{
                        "type":"int64",
                        "id":2
                    },
                    "y":{
                        "type":"int64",
                        "id":3
                    },
                    "wx":{
                        "type":"int64",
                        "id":4
                    },
                    "wy":{
                        "type":"int64",
                        "id":5
                    }
                }
            },
            "Flag":{
                "fields":{
                    "time":{
                        "type":"int64",
                        "id":1
                    },
                    "name":{
                        "type":"string",
                        "id":2
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Then it creates a new instance of the "InteractionCollection" message and pushes new interactions, mouseMovements and flags to it.

```
instance = message.create({
    url : "someurl",
    interactions : [],
    mouseMovements : []
})

var some_interaction = interaction_message.create({
    time : Date.now(),
    elementId : "idstring",
    elementType : "typestring",
    type : "anotherstring",
    additionalInfo : "infostring"
});
instance.interactions.push(some_interaction);
```

At the end of the script it then posts the data in serialized format to the server like this:

```
navigator.sendBeacon("someserverpath", message.encode(instance).finish());
```

Im working with C# so I installed the official Google Protocol Buffer Package via NuGet (Google.Protobuf) and created a proto file to replicate the json descriptor from above:

```
syntax = "proto3";
option csharp_namespace = "Proto2"; //C# Project Name: Proto2

message InteractionCollection {
    repeated Interaction interactions = 1;
    repeated MouseMovement mouse_movements = 2;
    string url = 3;
    repeated Flag flags = 4;

    message Flag {
        int64 time = 1;
        string name = 2;
    }

    message Interaction {
        string type = 1;
        int64 time = 2;
        string element_id = 3;
        string element_type = 4;
        string additional_info = 5;
    }

    message MouseMovement {
        int64 time = 1;
        int64 x = 2;
        int64 y = 3;
        int64 wx = 4;
        int64 wy = 5;
    }
}
```

Then I compiled the proto file using protoc.exe, which comes with the NuGet Package, and included the resulting class in my project. I then created a test InteractionCollection and serialized it:

```
InteractionCollection collection = new InteractionCollection
{
    Url = "/",
    Interactions = {
    new Interaction{ Time = 1508602241363, ElementId = "DOM", ElementType = "DOM", Type = "tohru", AdditionalInfo = "" },
    new Interaction{ Time = 1508602243075, Type = "focus", AdditionalInfo = "" },
    },
};
using (var output = File.Create("csharp_out.dat"))
{
    collection.WriteTo(output);
}
```

And on the website it serialized the same exact Message.

```
{
"interactions":[
    {"type":"tohru","time":"1508602241363","elementId":"DOM","elementType":"DOM","additionalInfo":""},
    {"type":"focus","time":"1508602243075","additionalInfo":""}
],
"url":"/"
}
```

However, the data I get from my C# project differs slightly from the data the website posts. Is my proto file wrong or is there another reason for this. Obviously, this means I can't deserialize the data from the website either.
C#:

```
tohruÓÂÍýó+DOM"DOM

focusƒÐÍýó+/
```

or

```
\x0A\x18\x0A\x05\x74\x6F\x68\x72\x75\x10\xC3\x93\xC3\x82\xC3\x8D\xC3\xBD\xC3\xB3\x2B\x1A\x03\x44\x4F\x4D\x22\x03\x44\x4F\x4D\x0A\x0E\x0A\x05\x66\x6F\x63\x75\x73\x10\xC6\x92\xC3\x90\xC3\x8D\xC3\xBD\xC3\xB3\x2B\x1A\x01\x2F
```

JS:

```
tohruÓÂÍýó+DOM"DOM*

focusÐÍýó+*/
```

or

```
\x1A\x0A\x05\x74\x6F\x68\x72\x75\x10\xC3\x93\xC3\x82\xC3\x8D\xC3\xBD\xC3\xB3\x2B\x1A\x03\x44\x4F\x4D\x22\x03\x44\x4F\x4D\x2A\x0A\x10\x0A\x05\x66\x6F\x63\x75\x73\x10\xC2\x83\xC3\x90\xC3\x8D\xC3\xBD\xC3\xB3\x2B\x2A\x1A\x01\x2F
```

Im sorry for this being such a long question but I have fiddled around with it for more than a week and I truly can't figure out what the problem is. Thank you for your patience!

**UPDATE:**

After some testing, running protobufjs locally I noticed that the C# version of Protobuf interprets an empty string as null and therefore leaves the entire field out (like when you leave out an optional field) whereas protobufjs serializes it to:

```
\x12\x00
```

I also tried the same test with protobuf-net instead of the Google version and it serialized the empty string to:

```
\x12\x20
```

Is there a way to change this behaviour to the one that protobufjs uses?

Comment: It would be easier to read if you post hex representations of encoded messages

Comment: Are you able to run the protobufjs code yourself? If so, you can try reducing this to a much simpler proto and try to isolate where the difference is. You could also try looking at the [wire format](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/encoding) and look at each version of the data through that lens.

Comment: Hey, I just tried running protobufjs myself with a much simpler proto (basically a message with only a string) and checked and the bytes are identical. Ill have a look into the wire format.